# Netbeans doesn't show up after being installed as root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans

I installed netbeans in Ubuntu Linux 11.04 as root.

It installed completely but after logging out as root and logging in as a normal administrator, Netbeans doesn't show in applications and neither does it show on the desktop using a shortcut.

However when I try to reinstall the application says its already installed. What should I do to make it show in the applications panel of a normal user or even create a shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how to create desktop shortcut. You can copy this content but you have to correct paths, especially version of Netbeans

1. create file netbeans.desktop in your Desktop directory
   `cd ~/Desktop; touch netbeans.desktop`
2. insert this content to that file but **correct** paths

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
>
> [Desktop Entry]
> Encoding=UTF-8
> Name=NetBeans IDE 7.1.1
> Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
> Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-7.1.1/bin/netbeans"
> Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-7.1.1/nb/netbeans.png
> Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
> Version=1.0
> Type=Application
> Terminal=0
> ```

You can run for example this command `gedit netbeans.desktop`. That should work

Comment: Don't forget to make the desktop file executable, otherwise cautious-laucnher won't run it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command with a correct path in your terminal

root@kali:sh /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans

This will work when you enter correct path after netbeans-8.2